# Identical loadDocument requests randomly throws 403

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are facing issues where identical requests for a model manifest using `Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load` results in different responses, so at seemingly random we receive '403 Forbidden' with no further information as to what went wrong or why, so we're pretty much at a loss.

It seems to happens randomly during a session with different model loads. At some point a model will just not load due to the 403 response. But a few moments later trying to load the same or another model, there are no issues at all.

We have suspected if our Forge tokens were not renewed properly, but we are using the viewer's `refreshToken(..)` to refresh the token and it seems to work fine, also seeing that trying to load the same or another model again a few moments later often (not everytime) works fine. Is there a way to validate the current token before trying perhaps?

For reference, I've attached image of two requests for the exact same model, one failing and one succesful loaded within the same session. There's not a lot of differences to see (also why I'm seeking help here), however in the failing one, of them there seem to be a cloudfront error(?), i.e.   `X-Cache: Error from cloudfront`.

[Requests comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r7ZV.png)

I've tried debugging my way through the entire process, both in succesful and failing responses. I see no differences in the requests (other than token(?)), only the response.

Have anyone seen something similar or have any ideas at all as to resolving this issue?

Best regards,
Niklas

Comment: sorry about this, we'll get back to you soon, once we receive the insights.